# Replying on the same thread in a mailing list using git send-email

Tags: git, email, mailing-list, git-send-email

I had submitted a patch to an organisation’s mailing list and now need to send a
revised version of the patch on the same thread using git send-email. I have set
my chainreplyto value to false. I had tried this earlier:

```r
git send-email --no-chain-reply-to --to=mailing-list@organisation.org \
--in-reply-to='[org-devel] [PATCH] Added functionality' Added-functionality.patch
```

This is creating a new thread instead of replying to the already existing one.
What would be the correct way of replying?

Answer (score 17):

Use `Message-id` instead of the subject in the `--in-reply-to` option.

```
--in-reply-to=<Message-id>
```

You can find the `Message-Id` value in the header of the message you want to reply to.